# Using Ajax to post data to another website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am new here and I am having trouble with the $.ajax.
How I can post data to a website that I have already known the header's information (API,content-type,...). This website allows me to get data from it, that's why it provides me the header's data :

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://anotherwebsite.com/',
type: 'post',
headers: {
'Api-Key'    : '1234567891011121314',
'Accept'     : 'application/blablabla+json; version=10',
'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
},
data: { 
"value" : "value 1";
}
success: function (result) {
               console.log(result);
            },
});
```

And the console.log told me "404 (Not Found)"

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Check your console for errors or warnings. Also check the status response of that request. If that is not your website - so that you could make adjustments to response headers - or it doesn't expect for somebody to make requests from a different site to it, it won't work (at least not from the browser).

Comment: Hi ! The console.log told me "404 (Not Found)". That website allows me to get data. Moreover, I tried on Postman and It worked but now when I do it with localhost it doesn't work.

Comment: And that website I want to post is rest API